# onCreate sometimes running in background

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm not quite sure how to debug the phenomenon I'm currently seeing in my Android application.
I have an Activity which is just doing some networking stuff (which needs to be done in background).
This activity is launched from a PreferencesFragment using an Intent.
When the user selects the preference item, the Intent is fired and the Activity is started (then it does the networking stuff and quits using finish()).

I created an AsyncTask to perform the networking actions in the background.
(I thought that onCreate will most probably run in the UI thread...)
But then, an exception occurred:
java.lang.RuntimeException:  Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Did onCreate() already run in the background???

To test that, I moved the networking functions directly into onCreate().
This was working well...
... at least several times.

Suddenly, an exception was thrown:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Moving the code back to the AsyncTask helped... for some time.

Does anyone know why this phenomenon might occur?
Are there scenarios when onCreate() runs in the UI thread and others when onCreate() runs in background?

My class is as simple as this:

```
public class ReregisterInDb extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        new ReregisterAsyncTask().execute(""); // solution 1

            // solution 2
        //GCMFunctions gcmFunctions = new GCMFunctions(getApplicationContext());
        //gcmFunctions.registerInDb();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        finish();
    }

    class ReregisterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            GCMFunctions gcmFunctions = new GCMFunctions(getApplicationContext());
            gcmFunctions.registerInDb();
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you even start an activity for this? It seems to me that you can declare the async task as a separate class and just use that... Regardless, you shouldn't use an activity for the sole purpose of doing background work - either start an AsyncTask from your current activity or use a service.

Comment: I would like to avoid using a service just for this purpose. The programming overhead seems too much. I know that the current implementation is not very smart... But how to start an AsyncTask from a PreferencesFragment? I can just fire Intents which then launch Activities. Maybe there's a better solution...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the reason for this strange behavior.
I did not post the contents of the registerInDb() method.
In that method, there is a Toast:

```
Toast.makeText(context, 
  "Not currently registered with GCM. [...]", 
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This message is causing the exceptions...

The solution is:

- call the function in the UI thread so that the Toast messages work and
  enter code heremove the AsyncTask to only cover the actual network code.

Sorry for not giving all the details. I did not think that the Toast message was the root cause.

I learned that you cannot have Toasts in AsyncTasks. The always have to run on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything before calling `super.onCreate(...)` put that right at the beginning as I've shown below. EDIT: Also, your use of `getApplicationContext` in the AsyncTask is likely causing an issue, try creating a global Context variable and initializing that in onCreate and see if that works.

```
Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = this;
    new ReregisterAsyncTask().execute(""); // solution 1

    finish();
}

class ReregisterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        GCMFunctions gcmFunctions = new GCMFunctions(mContext);
        gcmFunctions.registerInDb();
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I changed the code accordingly, but after some tries, I still get an exception thrown (java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()). So, the flaky behaviour still exists.

Comment: @TomS I just noticed you're using `getApplicationContext` inside the AsyncTask. This is a bad idea and I'm fairly certain it is the source of your problems. Refer to my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

try to move the call of the method finish() of the activity in the method onPostExecute of async task

Comment: will the calling activity then be "finish()"ed? Or how do I specify that I would like to finish() the caller?

Comment: I still see the same behavior.